# Have a Javascript code that won't load with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, squarespace

I'm using Squarespace to make a website and on one of the pages, I'm using JavaScript to make the header different than all the other pages. I was able to use this code:

```css
<style>
    a.Header-branding {
        content:url("my url") !important;
        max-width: 290px;
    }
</style>
```

It works perfectly on the back end of the website, but when it comes to the front end I have to continually refresh in order to make it work. From what I've found it needs to be Ajax-enabled to work and I have no idea how to with Ajax.

If someone with Ajax knowledge could help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That's CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: What is the context of your code snippet? Where is it located? How, when and where does it get loaded?

Comment: Sorry, I meant CSS. It is used for a header image on an about page. All of the other pages have a white header, but this needs black because the background is white. So, it's set in the custom code section for just that page.